# error 2296: '^' : illegal , left operand has type 'double'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, operands

**Part of my code:**

```
double function (double x)
{
   f = x^5-3*x^4+3*x^3-2*x^2-5;
   return f;
}
```

**Problem**: I am getting following errors for this part of the code:

- error C2296: '^' : illegal , left operand has type 'double'
- error C2297: '^' : illegal , right operand has type 'double'

**My Goal:** I am writing a code to find the roots of the following polynomial in C++, Visual Studio 2012: 
[image]

I am not sure how to solve this error since I am learning C++ and this is my first time I encountered this error. There are only two aforementioned errors; rest of my code is error-free. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If I may, I suggest not squishing long formulas together without any space at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` operator in C/C++ is not an exponent operator (by default) - it's a bitwise XOR operator, and doesn't work on doubles.

Instead, use the [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) function.

Comment: It's not a very good exponent operator not by default because of its precedence.

Comment: @chris: Agreed, I just meant that it is possible for ^ to be overloaded and so some classes may potentially use it to mean exponent.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I was aware that `pow` function might work. But I don't know how exactly I can put the `pow` to work with my incorrect code. Can you please help me by showing how to re-write my aforementioned code using `pow` function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Smith: Where you have `x^5` change it to `pow(x,5)` etc.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Wow! It was easy. Thanks again! :)